# How to flatten json produced?

Tags: ruby, rabl

I am just repeating the question because it was not answered earlier!

I'm starting out with Rabl and are trying to include a parent attribute but at the same level as the child.

This is what I have so far..

```
class Usertag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    attr_accessible :user_id, :tag_id
end
```

My index.json.rabl

```
object @usertag
attributes :id
child :tag do
  attributes :name
end
```

Produces

```
[{"usertag":{"id":1,"tag":{"name":"Dolor et non."}}},
```

How do I flatten the child node in the template so it produces

```
[{"usertag":{"id":1,"name":"Dolor et non."
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might modify `index.json.rabl` to use custom node:

```
object @usertag
attributes :id
node :name do |ut| 
  ut.tag.name
end
```

Hope it helps.